# Cannot see Eureka Server dashboard on browser, type=Not Found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

Created service registry module and service up and running but cannot access via browser getting
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

Console Logs

```
 [           main] c.c.registry.ServiceRegistryApplication  : Started ServiceRegistryApplication in 2.469 seconds (JVM running for 3.114)
  INFO 9328 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
  INFO 9328 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
  INFO 9328 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
```

Application Code

```
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServiceRegistryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceRegistryApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.community</groupId>
    <artifactId>service-registry</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>service-registry</name>
    <description>Eureka Service Registry</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
        <!--<spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>-->
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>netflix-candidates</id>
            <name>Netflix Candidates</name>
            <url>https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

yaml

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

tried multiple combination of spring-cloud and sprint boot version but not able to load the eureka server dashboard.

Comment: cloud 2022.0 is not compatible with boot 2.x, it requires 3.0

Comment: thank you @spencergibb it worked for me after upgrading spring boot version to 3.0.2